# Is the app to print LEGO storage labels from www.bricklabels.com still available somewhere?

Tags: storage, organisation

It seemed like the perfect solution, so that I am not printing labels that I don't need.  However, the domain is for sale, and I am not well-versed in github so I don't know how to get the application from there.

Comment: I'm not aware of this being live anywhere. It looks like a web app, so it may be a little tricky to get running if you aren't familiar with those. For others, I think this is the Github repo: https://github.com/Gottwik/legolabels

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean http://www.legolabels.com?  That site still seems accessible.

Comment: Maybe they renamed themselves.  Those look very similar to what I remember on the other site.

Comment: In which case LEGO Groups legal department won’t be impressed.